# Can someone please explain the reducer function of this reducer function header?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript, redux, asp.net-core-3.0

This question may seem trivial for some, but I've been studying react, redux, and javascript for some time now. The only missing piece is the typescript. I want to understand the reducer function in this piece of code. Specifically the function header.

This code is directly taken from the example in visual studio code 2019 react redux template for ASP.net core 3.0. Specfically the WeatherForecast.ts file in the src/store folder. I couldn't find much documentations about this example as its pretty new. To my understanding it uses redux thunk with the function chaining pattern. What I think confuses me is the type casting with typescript. I understand the rest of the template pretty well, but I think its the typescript that throws me off for the reducer.

```
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';

// -----------------
// STATE - This defines the type of data maintained in the Redux store.

export interface WeatherForecastsState {
    isLoading: boolean;
    startDateIndex?: number;
    forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
}

export interface WeatherForecast {
    dateFormatted: string;
    temperatureC: number;
    temperatureF: number;
    summary: string;
}

// -----------------
// ACTIONS - These are serializable (hence replayable) descriptions of state transitions.
// They do not themselves have any side-effects; they just describe something that is going to happen.

interface RequestWeatherForecastsAction {
    type: 'REQUEST_WEATHER_FORECASTS';
    startDateIndex: number;
}

interface ReceiveWeatherForecastsAction {
    type: 'RECEIVE_WEATHER_FORECASTS';
    startDateIndex: number;
    forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
}

// Declare a 'discriminated union' type. This guarantees that all references to 'type' properties contain one of the
// declared type strings (and not any other arbitrary string).
type KnownAction = RequestWeatherForecastsAction | ReceiveWeatherForecastsAction;

// ----------------
// ACTION CREATORS - These are functions exposed to UI components that will trigger a state transition.
// They don't directly mutate state, but they can have external side-effects (such as loading data).

export const actionCreators = {
    requestWeatherForecasts: (startDateIndex: number): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        // Only load data if it's something we don't already have (and are not already loading)
        const appState = getState();
        if (appState && appState.weatherForecasts && startDateIndex !== appState.weatherForecasts.startDateIndex) {
            fetch(`api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts?startDateIndex=${startDateIndex}`)
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<WeatherForecast[]>)
                .then(data => {
                    dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_WEATHER_FORECASTS', startDateIndex: startDateIndex, forecasts: data });
                });

            dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_WEATHER_FORECASTS', startDateIndex: startDateIndex });
        }
    }
};

// ----------------
// REDUCER - For a given state and action, returns the new state. To support time travel, this must not mutate the old state.

const unloadedState: WeatherForecastsState = { forecasts: [], isLoading: false };

export const reducer: Reducer<WeatherForecastsState> = (state: WeatherForecastsState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): WeatherForecastsState => {
    if (state === undefined) {
        return unloadedState;
    }

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_WEATHER_FORECASTS':
            return {
                startDateIndex: action.startDateIndex,
                forecasts: state.forecasts,
                isLoading: true
            };
        case 'RECEIVE_WEATHER_FORECASTS':
            // Only accept the incoming data if it matches the most recent request. This ensures we correctly
            // handle out-of-order responses.
            if (action.startDateIndex === state.startDateIndex) {
                return {
                    startDateIndex: action.startDateIndex,
                    forecasts: action.forecasts,
                    isLoading: false
                };
            }
            break;
    }

    return state;
};
```

There are no errors. I just need to understand the semantics of these function headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the usual structure of an `async` action to a reducer, but using typescript.

Basically you define the data types as `interfaces` on the top, those are just objects defining what kind of data you're expecting to pass through.

Then, you have the action and the reducer.
The implementation of these is exactly the same as regular react-redux. However, you are implementing an `async` action (making an asynchronous call using `fetch`), so you also need to use `redux-thunk` and its type from typescript, `AppThunkAction`.

***Therefore, you need to specify what 'thing' (type of data) every function is expecting to pass.***

In case you need a particular data type (complex type), it's convenient to create an `interface` for it. Otherwise, you can repeat this complex type following the columns (`:`) of every object you want to assign it, but this is not recommended.

For example, if I'm expecting a object from an API call with `id`, `name`, `hobbies` and `timestamp`, an interface for that complex type would be:

```
export interface dataFromAPICall {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    hobbies?: string[];
    timestamp: number;
}
```

In this case, hobbies is optional (`?`) and it expects and array of strings `['football', 'sky', 'bodyboard surfing']`.

In case of complex types on popular libraries, it is common that those types are already defined, such as `AppThunkAction` in redux, or `ReactNode` in React.

Hope this helps!

Comment: so to my understanding this line:
`export const reducer: Reducer<WeatherForecastsState> = (state: WeatherForecastsState | undefined, incomingAction: Action): WeatherForecastsState => {` 

means we are defining a const variable called reducer that is of type Reducer<WeatherforecastsState> which equals an instance of the reducer function which is of the type WeatherForecastsState. ok would you mind pointing me to some typescript resources that I can read about and learn this type of intermediate notation?